# Get all values of Form using React Redux Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux-form

Is there any way to get all the values of a form when using react-redux-form?. `getField` seems to work on individual fields but not when called on the form model. I would really like to avoid using `getField` on each individual field in my form, as the number of fields is quite large.

**P.S: I am talking about the npm module [react-redux-form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form) and not the [redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) module.**

Comment: @Shubham Khatri. Please recheck the question you think this question is a duplicate of. It refers to the redux-form module and not the react-redux-form module.I think I have mentioned the module name quite clearly in my question

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, reverted the close vote

Comment: @Shubham Khatri No worries :)